# Comparing each line in CSV file to JSON hash on matching element to get unique matches only

Tags: ruby, loops, csv, compare, unique

I searched SO before posting but perhaps I don't know the correct search terms.

I successfully read the CSV file into a new array and am trying to compare the eighth element in the array to the JSON response of my program.  The JSON response from my program (`data["ip"]`) is just an IP address that matches what is in `row[8]`.

Everything is working for matches, however three non-matches will be found in every loop iteration. The only IP address that doesn't exist in the JSON is `100.100.100.300`,  all the others will have a match.

My Code:

```
require 'csv'
require 'json'
require 'date'

CSV.foreach("list.csv", :headers => true) do |row|
  @response["response"]["results"].each do |data| 
     if row[8].eql?(data["ip"])
      puts "Match: " + row[8] + " = " + data["ID"]
    else
      puts "No Match Found for " + row[8]
    end
  end
end
```

Here are the results I would like:

```
Match: 100.100.100.200 = 26826
Match: 100.100.100.100 = 26827
Match: 100.100.100.400 = 26827
No Match Found for 100.100.100.300
```

Here are the results I am getting:

```
No Match Found for 100.100.100.200
Match: 100.100.100.200 = 26826
No Match Found for 100.100.100.200
No Match Found for 100.100.100.200
No Match Found for 100.100.100.300
No Match Found for 100.100.100.300
No Match Found for 100.100.100.300
No Match Found for 100.100.100.300
Match: 100.100.100.100 = 26827
No Match Found for 100.100.100.100
No Match Found for 100.100.100.100
No Match Found for 100.100.100.100
No Match Found for 100.100.100.400
No Match Found for 100.100.100.400
No Match Found for 100.100.100.400
Match: 100.100.100.400 = 26827
```

'list.csv' looks like this:

```
Applicability,Person,Tier,Type,AType,Name,Code,Sub,IP Address,Location,Presence,Env,Main,Main2,Status,Contact,Group,FQDN,Outside,OutsideIdent,Category,Comments
Yes,Unit,Accepted,Level,Hardware,NameA,C1234565,Yes,100.100.100.200,"Nowhere",No,VP,Running,SomeKind,Active,"","",FullName,"","",Tool,""
Yes,Unit,Accepted,Level,Hardware,NameB,C1234566,Yes,100.100.100.300,"Nowhere",No,VP,Running,SomeKind,Inactive,"","",FullName,"","",Tool,""
Yes,"","",Something,Hardware,NameC,C1234567,Yes,100.100.100.100,"Nowhere",,"",,,"","Name, Contact","",FullNameFull,"","",Tool,""
Yes,"","",Something,Hardware,NameD,C1234568,No,100.100.100.400,"Nowhere",,"",,,"","Name, Contact","",FullNameFull,"","",Tool,""
```

Comment: I'd recommend reading "[ask]" and "[mcve]". We need a minimal example of the JSON in order to test your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not need two loops.  You could do as below:
(Not tested as JSON structure was not shared in question)

```
results = @response["response"]["results"]

CSV.foreach("list.csv", :headers => true) do |row|
  matching_entry  = results.find { |data| row["IP Address"] == data["ip"]}
  if matching_entry
    puts "Match: " + row["IP Address"] + " = " + matching_entry["ID"]
  else
    puts "No Match Found for " + row["IP Address"]]
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Wand Maker !  This works swimmingly.  I will re-read it soon and make sure I understand how it works for the future.

Comment: @KurtW Instead of `row[8]`, you could use `row["IP Address"]` as the CSV has headers.  I have updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it would be creating a hash with the IP address as key. The benefit is that it would only have to iterate once to create the lookup.

```
ip_table = Hash[@response['response']['results'].map {|x| [x['ip'], x['ID']]}]

CSV.foreach("list.csv", :headers => true) do |row| 
  if ip_table[row[8]]
    puts "Match: " + row[8] + " = " + ip_table[row[8]]
  else
    puts "No Match Found for " + row[8]
  end
end
```